# Issues with Typedef - need to ignore certain code

Tags: c++, sorting, typedef

Here's my biggest problem.

I'm working on a program that does a bunch of fast sorting algorithms. (Quick, Radix, and Merge).

However, I want to sort multiple types of data (lists of integers and strings, in particular). Therefore I decided to use Typedef in order to make my key variables able to change types.

In the Radix code, I have an area where I need to do integer mathematics. I wrote a version for integers, and a version for strings. (In the string version, I use stoi()).

**When I want to run the program using Integers, I need it to ignore areas of code that require stoi() conversion.**

### How can I make the compiler ignore code conditionally depending on what is in my typedef statement?

EDIT: I took the suggestion of using #ifndef to hide sections of code, **for now** because I primarily want to debug my code right now. (My Radix Sort is not working with strings.)

I'll try to work out the kinks of Template once all my code is working!

---

As requested, here is the code. Did not include code for actual functions.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include"Queue.h"
using namespace std;

// Global variables
ItemType Data[100000];      // Data array
Queue QArray[26];           // Array of Queues. 0-9 used for numbers, 0-25 used for characters/strings

// Functions
void QuickSort(ItemType Data[], int Lower, int Upper);
int Partition(ItemType Data[], int Lower,int Upper);
void RadixSort(ItemType Data[], int counter, int digits);
void MergeSort(ItemType Data[], int Lower, int Upper);
void Merge(int Lower, int Mid, int Upper);

// Main
int main()
{
    // Initialize and open the text files
    ifstream NumberInput, StringInput;
    ofstream QuickNumOut, QuickStrOut, RadixNumOut, RadixStrOut, MergeNumOut, MergeStrOut;
    NumberInput.open("Numbers.txt");
    StringInput.open("Strings.txt");
    QuickNumOut.open("QuickSortedNumbers.txt");
    QuickStrOut.open("QuickSortedStrings.txt");
    RadixNumOut.open("RadixSortedNumbers.txt");
    RadixStrOut.open("RadixSortedStrings.txt");
    MergeNumOut.open("MergeSortedNumbers.txt");
    MergeStrOut.open("MergeSortedStrings.txt");


    // Declare the variables
    time_t totaltime;   // Used to calculate run time of algorithms
    int counter = 0;    // Counter for items
    int choice, type;   // User chooses string or integer sort, and type of sort
    ItemType max;       // Largest number, used for Radix sort
    int digits = 0;     // Finds number of digits in max, for Radix sort

    cout << "Would you like to sort the list of (1) Numbers, or (2) Strings?  ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << "Would you like to use (1) Quick Sort, (2) Radix Sort, or (3) Merge Sort?  ";
    cin >> type;

    switch(type)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            // Switch statement to read information into array from the text files
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1: 
                {
                    // While loop reads in data until end of file is found
                    while(!NumberInput.eof())
                    {
                        NumberInput >> Data[counter];
                        counter++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    // While loop reads in data until end of file is found
                    while(!StringInput.eof())
                    {
                        StringInput >> Data[counter];
                        counter++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Close input files
            NumberInput.close();
            StringInput.close();

            // Start timer
            totaltime = time(0);
            // Perform QuickSort
            QuickSort(Data, 0, counter-1);
            // Stop timer
            totaltime = time(0) - totaltime;

            // Switch statement to print sorted list to text files
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                {
                    // For loop goes from 0 to the length of actual data in the array
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                        QuickNumOut << Data[i] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    // For loop goes from 0 to the length of actual data in the array
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                        QuickStrOut << Data[i] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Print out information
            cout << "QuickSort data written to file." << endl;
            cout << "Total time for QuickSort was " << totaltime << " seconds." << endl << endl;
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            // Reset counter
            counter = 0;

            // Reopen files
            NumberInput.open("Numbers.txt");
            StringInput.open("Strings.txt");

            // Switch statement to read information into array from the text files
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1: 
                {
                    max = Data[0];
                    // While loop reads in data until end of file is found
                    while(!NumberInput.eof())
                    {
                        NumberInput >> Data[counter];
                        if (Data[counter] > max)
                            max = Data[counter];
                        counter++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    /*
                    max = Data[0];
                    // While loop reads in data until end of file is found
                    while(!StringInput.eof())
                    {
                        StringInput >> Data[counter];
                        if (Data[counter] > max)
                            max = Data[counter];
                        counter++;
                    }*/
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Find out how many digits are in largest number
            while (max)
            {
                max /= 10;
                digits++;
            }

            // Close input files
            NumberInput.close();
            StringInput.close();

            // Start timer
            totaltime = time(0);
            // Perform QuickSort
            RadixSort(Data, counter, digits);
            // Stop timer
            totaltime = time(0) - totaltime;

            // Switch statement to print sorted list to text files
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                {
                    // For loop goes from 0 to the length of actual data in the array
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                        RadixNumOut << Data[i] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    // For loop goes from 0 to the length of actual data in the array
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                        RadixStrOut << Data[i] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Print out information
            cout << "RadixSort data written to file." << endl;
            cout << "Total time for RadixSort was " << totaltime << " seconds." << endl << endl;
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            // Reset counter
            counter = 0;

            // Reopen files
            NumberInput.open("Numbers.txt");
            StringInput.open("Strings.txt");

            // Switch statement to read information into array from the text files
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1: 
                {
                    // While loop reads in data until end of file is found
                    while(!NumberInput.eof())
                    {
                        NumberInput >> Data[counter];
                        counter++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    // While loop reads in data until end of file is found
                    while(!StringInput.eof())
                    {
                        StringInput >> Data[counter];
                        counter++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Close input files
            NumberInput.close();
            StringInput.close();

            // Start timer
            totaltime = time(0);
            // Perform QuickSort
            MergeSort(Data, 0, counter-1);
            // Stop timer
            totaltime = time(0) - totaltime;

            // Switch statement to print sorted list to text files
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                {
                    // For loop goes from 0 to the length of actual data in the array
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                        MergeNumOut << Data[i] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    // For loop goes from 0 to the length of actual data in the array
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                        MergeStrOut << Data[i] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Print out information
            cout << "MergeSort data written to file." << endl;
            cout << "Total time for MergeSort was " << totaltime << " seconds." << endl << endl;
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            cout << "Invalid choice.";
            break;
        }
    }

    // Close output files
    QuickNumOut.close();
    QuickStrOut.close();
    RadixNumOut.close();
    RadixStrOut.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Sounds like you're misunderstanding what typedefs are for. From what I can tell, a template is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that you handle the type recognition within an `switch` and not with a `typedef` (like you hinted in your subject). In that case - use **template** functions. It's really easy to implement - for example `QuickSort` will become:

```
template <typename T>
void QuickSort(T Data[], int Lower, int Upper)
{
   // Your current code operating on 'T' instead of 'int'/'string'
}
```

And so on. This solution will shorten your code by a ton.

And then you just use it like this:

```
switch(type){
   case 1:
      QuickSort<int>(table,lower,upper);
      break;
   case 2:
      QuickSort<string>(table,lower,upper);
}
```

Also - use **[containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)** instead of the array to make things even more simple. I would suggest `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I am using a queue for the Radix sort, and I have the typedef statement inside of the header file.

How would I treat numbers as strings? Right now I am reading in a text file with around 95,000 randomly generated numbers. The length varies on the strings.

Comment: I just edited my answer after reading deeper in your code. Check it out now :)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I have no idea what templates are, but I'll see if I can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-processor a section out of your code using something like:

```
#define IGNORE_STOI

...

#ifndef IGNORE_STOI
// string to int section of code
#endif
```

This will remove the section between the `#ifndef` and `#endif` statements if `IGNORE_STOI` is defined.